Conhost filters control characters
When using cmd.exe it normally starts as tab in conhost.
The problem is that conhost filters non-printable characters (here: ASCII 1-31)
which I require to be passed on to e.g., telnet
Is there a way to disable that stupid behavior?
The only workaround is to disable its use for cmd.exe by setting the registry to
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console]
"ForceV2"=dword:00000000

You can easily reproduce the issue.
Create a text with ASCII characters in e.g., Notepad++, copy it to the clipboard
and paste it in cmd.exe hosted and in cmd.exe run in legacy mode
